# Why don't these elements allign vertically?

Tags: html, css, centering, css-transforms

I've got the following HTML markup:

```
<section class="socialBar">
    <div style="width: 50%; height: 100%; border-right: 1px solid black;">
        <img src="dislike_32.jpg" alt="Dislike">
        <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%; height: 100%;">
        <img src="like_32.jpg" alt="Like">
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
</section>
```

And the following CSS:

```
section.socialBar > div{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
section.socialBar > div > *{
    position: relative; 
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

So basically, I have a `section`, that has 2 `divs` that are placed next to each other (using `display: inline-block`) and each take up half of the `section`. Now, inside them, we have one `img` and one `span`. The image and the span are supposed to be **vertically centered** using my second CSS selector. But instead, this is the result I get:

[image: the result]

The images (which are 24px * 24px) seem to be properly centered, but the two `span` elements are not. What's the problem here?

Comment: If you provide a snippet or jsfiddle, it'll be easier to figure it out.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh http://jsfiddle.net/6f8mertg/2/ The spans are alligned in the jsfiddle example, but the divs aren't displayed side by side??

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the `span` tags were inline elements, and therefore could not be centered. I simply added `display: inline-block` both to the `img` and `span` tags and it worked perfectly.